# yii2 ActiveForm & NavBar

Tags: yii2, activeform

Возникла проблема.

Есть меню

```
 <?php
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => 'SALVAGEDATA Partner Portal',
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
    ],
]);
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/index']];
} else {
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'New Case', 'url' => ['/site/case']];
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Payment History', 'url' => ['/site/payment-history']];
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Settings', 'url' => ['/site/settings']];
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Purchase Orders', 'url' => ['/site/orders']];
    $menuItems[] = '<li>'
        . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'], 'post')
        . Html::submitButton(
            'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
            ['class' => 'btn btn-link logout']
        )
        . Html::endForm()
        . '</li>';
}
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => $menuItems,
]);
NavBar::end();
?>
```

Как мне в него вставить ActiveForm?

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'search', ['options' => ['class' => 'col-lg-2']])->input('search')->label(false);  ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Пробовал много вариантов, не получается. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Добрый вечер. А зачем?

Comment: Чтобы оно было в меню сайта, если есть другой способ, буду рад о нём узнать.

Comment: Зачем форму поиска вставлять в меню сайта? Рядом разместить никак?

Comment: Вот именно, что никак) Нужно именно туда.
Если есть другой способ реализации этой проблемы, буду рад увидеть.

Answer (score 0):

```
NavBar::begin([
   // параметры виджета
]);

echo Nav::widget([
  'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
  'items' => $menuItems,
]);

$form = ActiveForm::begin();
echo $form->field($model, 'search')->textInput();
ActiveForm::end();

NavBar::end();
```

Или ещё один вариант.

```
$this->beginBlock('search');
  $form = ActiveForm::begin();
  echo $form->field($model, 'search')->textInput()->label(false);
  ActiveForm::end();
$this->endBlock();
```

В самом меню

```
  [
     'label' => 'Form',
     'items' => $this->blocks['search']
  ]
```

Опять же, подправить стили надо будет.

Хотя первый вариант, на мой взгляд, будет лучше.

Comment: Не работает.  Меню выводится в echo Nav::widget, а тот код снизу, который Вы прикрепили форму, ему некуда выводится.

Comment: А это уже стилями редактируйте

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Дополнил ответ ещё одним вариантом. Если помог - отмечайте решением для будущих соискателей ответа.